# How to split evenly and oddly a string to form an array of even and odd results OK Like

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php string formed by images and corresponding prices like OK Like

```
$myString = "ddb94-b_mgr3043.jpg,3800,83acc-b_mgr3059.jpg,4100";
```

I know  that if I do:

```
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
print_r($myArray);
```

I will get :

```
Array
(
    [0] => ddb94-b_mgr3043.jpg
    [1] => 3800
    [2] => 83acc-b_mgr3059.jpg
    [3] => 4100
)
```

But How could I split the string so I can have an associative array of the form?

```
Array
(
    "ddb94-b_mgr3043.jpg" => "3800"
    "83acc-b_mgr3059.jpg" => "4100"
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier way to do like below:-

```
<?php
$myString = "ddb94-b_mgr3043.jpg,3800,83acc-b_mgr3059.jpg,4100";
$chunks = array_chunk(explode(',', $myString), 2); //chunk array into 2-2 combination
$final_array = array();
foreach($chunks as $chunk){ //iterate over array
  $final_array[trim($chunk[0])] = trim($chunk[1]);//make key value pair
}
print_r($final_array); //print final array
```

Output:-https://eval.in/859757

Comment: It should be the answer

Comment: Outta box solution!! +1

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach to achieve this,

```
$myString = "ddb94-b_mgr3043.jpg,3800,83acc-b_mgr3059.jpg,4100,test.jpg,12321";
$arr = explode(",",$myString);
$temp = [];
array_walk($arr, function($item,$i) use (&$temp,$arr){
    if($i % 2 != 0) // checking for odd values
        $temp[$arr[$i-1]] = $item; // key will be even values
});
print_r($temp);
```

[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) - Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array

Here is your working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/47ceeb6622750bcf92d5231ef8d3389594e1097a).

Answer (score 2):

Try this Code... If you will receive all the key and value is equal it will work...

```
$myString = "ddb94-b_mgr3043.jpg,3800,83acc-b_mgr3059.jpg,4100";
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
$how_many = count($myArray)/2;
for($i = 0; $i <= $how_many; $i = $i + 2){
  $key = $myArray[$i];
  $value = $myArray[$i+1];
  // store it here
  $arra[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($arra);
```